# Mixer brush tool uses desaturated colour instead of the selected colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, brush, blending, painting

Whenever I'm blending using the Mixer brush tool it will use a slightly desaturated colour instead of the colour I have seleced. Here is what I mean:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsh70.png)

When I use any non blending brush for lining or broad colours its fine. It doesn't do it unless I'm going over another colour, you know... To blend them. Oh and this all started after I updated photoshop about a week ago.
I feel out of ideas on how to fix this. Here's a list of things I've done to try and resolve the problem that have failed.

1. Resetting the tool
2. Resetting the preferences
3. Adjusting wet/load/mix/flow
4. Adjusting most if not all of the brush settings
5. Resetting Photoshop
6. Restarting my computer
7. Changing Gamma blending as well as a couple other things in the Colour settings. (Don't know those settings very well so I didn't change much.)
8. Changing files/layers/colours
9. Using older versions of Photoshop through the Adobe Cloud (All still have the same problem now)

Just to be clear, it's not an issue with the brush not blending. The Blending works. It's all about the colour coming out desaturated compared to what I have selected. It makes painting and choosing the colours to paint with kind of impossible.

[This picture shows that my selected colour isn't being used when I'm blending.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVT3Y.jpg)

Comment: I never saw anything like that. Could you please upload a demo psd and a demo brush I could try to see the issue?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't really understand your question.  The Mixer Brush in Photoshop blends the existing colour with the colour loaded in the brush, so it's going to look different from something you'd paint with the regular Brush Tool. This is exactly how it's supposed to work.  If you don't want the colours to blend, then don't use the Mixer Brush.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks you! I've had trouble explaining my question before due to how strange it is so apologies if I wasn't clear. I know how the Mixer brush works, I've been using it for a little over a year and a half now. It's not that it's blending that's an issue, it's that it blends using a desaturated version of my selected colour. The more you'd go over the same area, the closer it should get to the selected colour. That's how it's always worked but now since the update it goes to a colour that isn't inbetween the base color and selected color. I'll add a picture to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy I've never done this before. Do I just upload the .psd file somewhere? I'm not quite sure how to upload a demo brush. When I look it up I'm only finding how to install brushes into photoshop, not create them.

Comment: To save a brush go to `Window > Brush Presets`, create a new Preset from the mixer brush you have a problem with (make sure you have "include tool settings" option turned ON) and then in the flyout menu (top-right corner of the panel with four lines icon) there will be `Export Selected Brushes` options — this will save an `.abr` file with this preset. To upload files you can use something like https://wetransfer.com/.

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy https://we.tl/t-bwENKZB4pu here is the link for both the .psd file and the brush. Note that it's not just this brush, but any brush I use that can blend that has this issue now. If I turn wet down to 0% it no longer desaturates the colour, but then it also doesn't blend at all, in which case there's no reason to use the mixer brush in the first place. I know it's a super strange bug, I couldn't find anything on this through my hours of trouble shooting and a lot of this file sharing stuff is new for me as well so I appreciate the help and patience.

Comment: @Arttredacks - the problem is I don't think it is "desaturating" the colour.  You may be describing it that way, but that's not what is actually going on. It looks like it's blending the colours as expected.

Comment: @BillyKerr I appreciate the help but the picture I added to my post should show that it's improperly desaturating the selected color. If it was blending right, wouldn't it be creating a color between the first 2 points instead of going left and up from my selected color? Id also like to reiterate that this is a brand new problem. In the year and a half that I've been using the Mixer brush to paint with, my selected color was what it would eventually blend into given enough overlap. The color I get now, no matter how intensely I paint over top of it, is never the same color I have selected.

Answer (score 0):

Your preset has `Wetness` and some `Mix` values, wet brushes will *never* give you the same color on the canvas as on picker (well, maybe after 100-ish strokes).

[image]

Why it gets desaturated? That's a question to Adobe about the way they made Mixer Brush to mix colors. Sometimes it "catches" colors from transparent areas, sometimes it gets "dirty". it's just the way Mixer Brush operates. For example after 5-10 strokes with your tool my color got some tints of green from somewhere:

[image]

But normally you don't want to lay colors with a wet brush. What I'd suggest is to lay your colors with Mix Brush with `0% Wetness` OR a normal brush and then smudge the borders to your liking.

[image]